# Remove/hide client sender ip from postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, ip

I'm trying to hide the client IP from emails sent from postfix.

here is an example of what I mean:

```
Received: from mail.[removed].com (adsl-75-37-61-254.dsl.frs2ca.sbcglobal.net [75.37.61.254])
    (using TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mail.[removed].com (Postfix) with ESMTP id D50C7BF185DD
    for <[removed]@gmail.com>; Thu,  2 Aug 2012 16:14:21 +0900 (JST)
Date: Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:14:08 +0000
```

Notice this line `(adsl-75-37-61-254.dsl.frs2ca.sbcglobal.net [75.37.61.254])`

I want to remove that line from the email.

I've tried doing this:

/etc/postfix/main.cf :

```
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
```

smtp_header_checks :

```
/^((.*) [(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])])/    IGNORE
```

But my IP address is still inside of the received part of the email. If I send email off the smtp server locally the IP address becomes `localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]`

How can I remove client IPs from the header?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `main.cf`:

```
smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
```

In `dynamicmaps.cf`:

```
# Use your real path to dict_pcre.so, below
pcre    /usr/lib/postfix/dict_pcre.so           dict_pcre_open
```

You should put this in your `/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks`:

```
/^Received: .*/     IGNORE
/^X-Originating-IP:/    IGNORE
```

Then run

```
# /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

Comment: My ip address is still displayed. I appreciate the efforts.

Comment: It is not necessary to have postfix-pcre. Regexp works the same way.

Comment: Alright. I have made sure pcre was install on the system. I have changed `regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks` to `pcre:/...`. I have then restarted postfix and monitored maillog for any errors. No errors were displayed. The email still displays my ip. XD Thanks for the efforts, Mike.

Comment: Hmm... I get an error but I found this http://www.irbs.net/internet/postfix/0404/1097.html I tested the regex with this http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html using argument: `postmap -q "Received: from mail.[removed].com (adsl-75-37-61-254.dsl.frs2ca.sbcglobal.net [75.37.61.254])" pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks` and the output was `IGNORE` so it is working. However it is not making changes in the email... Is the field inside `main.cf` wrong?

Comment: I updated the answer with a little more info... what kind of linux / unix is this running on?  I am testing now on my debian squeeze w/ `postfix-pcre`

Comment: Shit man. I just wasted your time. It's my fault in the very beginning. `smtp_header_checks` was supposed to be `header_checks`... It works now. I'm so sorry I wasted your time. I appreciate your efforts. Thank you. pcre also works too. I'm on centos. Thanks again, bro.

Comment: on ubuntu 20, I can't find `/usr/lib/postfix/dict_pcre.so`

Answer (score 14):

To remove the sender IP from the Received header for new mail submissions, use the `header_checks` key instead of the `smtp_header_checks` option:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks_submission
```

The `smtp_header_checks` option only applies to mail that is sent from Postfix to external servers whereas the `header_checks` option applies to incoming mail sent from your client to Postfix.

See also the *How Postfix receives mail* at http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html for an overview of the components, mail goes from smtpd -> cleanup -> incoming queue. The `smtpd` process receives mail and injects the `Received` header with the sender IP address. The [`header_checks(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) option is processed by the [`cleanup(8)`](http://www.postfix.org/cleanup.8.html) component which sanitizes email headers.

It is **not** recommended to set such a `header_checks` option globally in your main.cf as this would modify the Received header in *all* emails, even those received from external servers. Instead, you should configure your client to send email through a dedicated submission service on port 587, and configure Postfix to rewrite the headers for these authenticated submissions only.

In `/etc/postfix/master.cf`, add the following `-o` lines after the `submission` line:

```
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  # Require SASL authentication
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  # Require TLS transport security, do not leak your credentials in plaintext.
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt`
  # Disallow unauthenticated users from sending mail through this port.
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  # Use a different cleanup service (see below)
  -o cleanup_service_name=ascleanup
```

Time to configure the **cleanup** service for **a**uthenticated **s**ubmissions. I pick the name `ascleanup` to keep it short and aligned, but any name works. To do so, duplicate the **cleanup** service line in the same `master.cf` file, but rename the first field and add a new option to select the filter file:

```
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
ascleanup unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
  -o header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks_submission
```

(Use of the `pcre` table requires installing `postfix-pcre` on Debian, that will automatically take care of updating the dynamicmaps.cf file. No further changes are needed for this.)

The final piece is the actual filter configuration in `/etc/postfix/header_checks_submission`. You could potentially use something like:

```
/^Received: .*/ IGNORE
```

which will remove full Received header line, but instead you can also just drop the `from helo.host (reverse.host.name [192.0.2.1])` part while preserving other information:

```
/^Received: from [^ ]+ \([^ ]+ \[[IPv0-9a-f:.]+\]\)\s+(.* \(Postfix\) with .+)$/ REPLACE Received: $1
```

If you did change the [`mail_name`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mail_name) option, do change the `Postfix` word to match your configuration. (This pattern is accurate based on the Postfix source code, [smtpd/smtpd.c](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/e1b52f45e32e042b84c935f2a29baadefc62ff2d/postfix/src/smtpd/smtpd.c#L3328-L3331).)

I tested this with postfix 3.4.7-0+deb10u1 on Debian buster.
For another great description with the same approach, see [When sending email with Postfix, how can I hide the sender’s IP and username in the Received header?](https://askubuntu.com/a/78168/6969)

With the above modification, the following is turned into `Received: by ...`:

```
Received: from debian (unknown [IPv6:fe80::b036:2ff:fe6e:73f4])
        by mail.example.nl (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 1571B910B
        for <some@example.com>; Sun, 12 Jan 2020 02:23:15 +0000 (UTC)
```

Comment: this does not work on ubuntu 20. results in email sending failure

Comment: Note: you also need to add `-o cleanup_service_name=ascleanup` to the `smtps` service in `master.cf`, otherwise Received-Headers are only removed for email submitted over port 587, but not for email submitted over port 465.

Answer (score 3):

Open /etc/postfix/master.cf and find:

`cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup`

Add below those line and become:

`cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
  -o header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks`

Edit /etc/postfix/header_checks and add below codes:

`/^Received:/ IGNORE`

Now restart postfix. Let say on CentOS:

`service postfix restart`

Comment: Unfortunately, this will also strip the `Received` header on incoming mail.

Comment: then got error: 451 4.3.0 Error: queue file write error

Answer (score 1):

Using `IGNORE` causes trouble with mail signing filters, such as OpenDKIM. So,  postfix documentation [suggests us to use `REPLACE` clause instead.](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html) See the [documentation for `REPLACE`](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) clause usage.

#### Step 1:

Create a regular expressions file in `/etc/postfix/header_checks` and add the following information.

```
/^Received:.*with ESMTPSA/  REPLACE Received: You can't see me ;-)
/^X-Originating-IP:/        IGNORE
/^X-Mailer:/                IGNORE
/^Mime-Version:/            IGNORE
```

Since I only sent emails through port 465 (and don't allow SASL via port 25), I'm matching `ESMTPSA`—which works fine for me.

#### Step 2:

Add these two lines in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

#### Step 3:

Rebuild the hash table for postfix.

```
$ postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks
$ postfix reload
```

Now, try sending a test email, you'd see `Received: You can't see me ;-)` as the `Received` header. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
/^Received: from .*127.0.0.1**/ IGNORE
```

only use single `*` in both ends

Comment: Or more like it? 
/^Received: from .*127\.0\.0\.1.*/ IGNORE