# postfix - different header checks for incoming and outgoing mail

Tags: email, postfix, smtp-headers

How can I apply different `header_checks` for incoming and outoing mail using postfix?

By default, all header_checks are applied to both incoming and outgoing.

Comment: For anyone coming from search, this answer might give a clue on how to implement this: https://serverfault.com/a/998993/153238

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`header_checks` is done by `cleanup` so I don't think you can apply it only for incoming or outgoing.

`smtp_header_checks` is applied only for outgoing mail (smtp client)

Comment: Hm, thanks. That's a little bit better then only having `header_checks`. However, this still leaves me with problems: 1) `smtp_header_checks` is only used when mail leaves your server, so mail between users won't get filtered. 2)`header_checks` still is executed for both incoming and outgoing, it is not possible to have checks only for incoming

Comment: header_checks it is applied for incoming mail. But for postfix everything is incoming, local or internet. If you need to do it only for locally delivered emails maybe you can do it at another level, for example in MDA (procmail for example).

Comment: Okay, I think I am going to do it like this: mail 'send' by a local user is going to either get filtered by `smtp_headers_check` OR by a MDA if is being sent to another local user. All checks of mails received from other domains are also going to be done by the MDA. Do you think it's going to work like that or are there any problems I did not see?

Answer (score 3):

If there is a mail header which you can use to identify which is incoming and which is outgoing mail, with postfix 3.2 or newer you can short-circuit the [header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html), like:

```
/^Received: .*detect_outgoing_mails/ PASS
/^X-Something: this rule will only match on incoming mails/ HOLD
```

(but it still gives you only option to match ALL (as before) or to match only incoming or only outgoing mail, and requires relatively new postfix version)

As a better alternative, if you can always receive "outgoing" mail (mail from clients for whom you act as mail relay server) on one port (submission: tcp/587) and incoming mail on tcp/25, you should be able to use `master.cf` to override header_checks for each one, like this:

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks.relay

smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       200     smtpd
  -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
  -o header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks.mx
```

but that won't work if your clients for whom you relay also use tcp/25 as rest of the world. If they do, you could setup alternative port for them and it would work, but feasibility of that depends on your ability to persuade all your users to change their settings.

If you have extra IP to spare, you could also make it mostly transparent for users: let's say you had `smtp.example.org` as both relay server for users and as your MX with IP `a.a.a.a`, you could change domain's MX to IP `b.b.b.b`, and then use one smtpd server at `a.a.a.a` with one set of header checks, and another smtpd server at `b.b.b.b` with another set of header checks. This is even easier if you relay only for users from say 192.168.x.x/24 when you could even keep same DNS name and use DNS views to present internal IP for internal clients, and external IP for rest of the world.

And third way is so to use postfix [FILTER](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html) capability instead of `header_check` - instead of simple regexp matching, it will forward whole message to your custom script for processing, which can then easily distinguish between incoming and outgoing mail by inspecting headers, and then do any postprocessing as wanted.

Comment: also see http://serverfault.com/questions/658106/how-to-block-attachments-on-incoming-mails-only-using-postfix

Comment: plaese note you can't use header_checks in smtpd in master.cf, as it's implemented by cleanup, not smtpd

Comment: Yep, so need to use `smtpd` option called `cleanup_service_name` and define such an alternate in `master.cf`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do this through the 
`/etc/postfix/header_checks` file, something like this for the out going mail
`/^From: "spammer/ REJECT`      `/^To: bob@here.com/ REDIRECT bob@there.com`

I did this long time ago so dont remember all the details but you can get more info from here [DOC](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html)

This would allow you to define a action depending on whether mail is incoming or outgoing, I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I am looking for. I want to apply different `header_checks` to incoming/outgoing mail. I do not want to do a certain action depending on incoming/outgoing.

Comment: The reason for this is that I need to modify some headers depending on where the mail is coming from. As header_checks is line-based, I cannot achieve this using a single header_checks file.

Comment: This worked for my use case. I wanted to block messages from a domain while also being able to refer to that domain internally between the accounts on my email server.