# How to block attachments on incoming mails only using Postfix?

Tags: postfix, attachment

I have a mail server (CentOS 6.5) running Postfix and Dovecot

Postfix is listening on port 25 for inbound mail and 587 for outbound mail

The problem is outbound mail with pdf attachments are being blocked where I only want inbound mail with pdf attachments blocked.

I have this configuration line in main.cf

```
 mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/blocked_attachments
```

The blocked_attachments file contains:

```
/name=[^>]*\.(pdf|zip)/ REJECT
```

So incoming mail with a pdf attachment correctly is blocked, but when I compose an email with a PDF that is also blocked when I try and send.

How can I tell postfix that I only want incoming attachments filtered? Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 8):

I will rewrite your question become:

**How can I use different _header_checks for smtpd (port 25) and submission (port 587)?**

This canonical problem can be divided with several conditions

1. I want turn off header_checks for one of smtpd or submission.
2. I want to run different header_checks for smtpd and submission.

### 1. I want turn off header_checks for one of smtpd or submission.

For the example I assume that *you want to turn off the header_checks for submission (outgoing email)*.

**Solution 1: receive_override_options method**

You can use postfix parameter called [receive_override_options](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#receive_override_options). With the parameter you can override global header_check switch, so the filter won't run.
    #main.cf
    header_checks = pcre:/path/to/header_checks

```
#master.cf
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
```

Caveats: this will turn off ALL _header_checks and body_checks defined in [man 5 header_checks](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html). For the completed control which parameter that will be turned off, see Solution 2.

**Solution 2: Multiple cleanup service method**

We can **multiple-cleanup-service technique** for your problem as `*_header_checks` was performed by [cleanup](http://www.postfix.org/cleanup.8.html) service. You can see the example of this setup in [amavisd-new tutorial](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/README.postfix.html#d0e1110).

The magic parameter for this configuration is [cleanup_service_name](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#cleanup_service_name). With this parameter, we can use different cleanup service for each smtpd process. First we define one additional cleanup service (called no-headerchecks) in master.cf

```
no-headerchecks unix    n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
    -o mime_header_checks=
```

In this cleanup, we define empty mime_header_checks to disable filtering. The last step is tell submission service to use our no-headerchecks

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o cleanup_service_name=no-headerchecks
```

### 2. I want to run different header_checks for smtpd and submission.

For this problem you can use multiple cleanup service method as described above.

First we define one additional cleanup service (called second-headerchecks) in master.cf

```
second-headerchecks unix    n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
    -o mime_header_checks=pcre:/path/to/2ndheaderchecks
```

In this cleanup, we define second mime_header_checks to other PCRE table. The last step is tell submission service to use our second-headerchecks

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o cleanup_service_name=second-headerchecks
```

Note:

- Your case looks similar with [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/510855/218590). Unfortunately [the answer from Laurentiu Roescu](https://serverfault.com/a/510887/218590) only works if you want enable header_checks for **outgoing mail** that use smtp as transport. The good news is his first sentence about `cleanup` daemon gives us some idea for second solution.
- Multiple cleanup service method can be applied if you want different header_checks, body_checks and other parameters defined in `man 5 header_checks`.

Answer (score 1):

in /etc/postfix/master.cf, not /etc/postfix/main.cf, add (nb must be tabbed spaces):

```
second-headerchecks unix    n   -   n   -   0   cleanup
    -o mime_header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/2ndheaderchecks
submission inet n   -   n   -   -   smtpd
    -o cleanup_service_name=second-headerchecks
#
first-headerchecks unix n   -   n   -   0   cleanup
    -o mime_header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/1stheaderchecks
smtp inet n -   n   -   -   smtpd
    -o cleanup_service_name=first-headerchecks
#
```

create /etc/postfix/1stheaderchecks, which in this case is to block incoming zip files, then create the .db file:

```
/name=[^>]*\.zip/ REJECT security issue - please contact....by phone
```

then create /etc/postfix/2ndtheaderchecks, to allow outgoing attachments (and create the .db file):

```
# this file being 2ndheaderchecks allows for the sending of zip etc files which otherwise might be blocked
# ie all files can be sent aside from .128 files...I didn't want to leave it blank as was not sure if that would work
/name=[^>]*\.128/ REJECT
```