# How to hide/remove original source IP address when using OpenSMTPD?

Tags: freebsd, openbsd, opensmtpd

I'm trying to figure out how to remove/hide the originating source IP address of every mail being sent using OpenSMTPD?

To do the equivalent in postfix, it would be:

http://integer13.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/hide-your-source-ip-with-emails-relayed-by-postfix/

http://blog.tenak.net/2011/04/2011-04-dont-send-client-ip-postfix.html

http://serverfault.com/questions/413533/remove-hide-client-sender-ip-from-postfix

I'm using OpenBSD.

Thanks!

Comment: You talk about opensmtpd and tagged your question with postfix. What do you use now?

Comment: I'm using postfix, and would like to know how to do the same thing in OpenSMTPD. Perhaps there would be someone who knows both and can help me to do the same thing in OpenSMTPD.

Comment: So your question is about opensmtpd. Then I can't answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.mail-archive.com/misc@opensmtpd.org/msg01483.html

(In the following, `mask-source` was changed to `mask-src` to reflect the current option name)

"To some extent, yes. You can use "mask-src":

listen on [...] mask-src

This will hide the IP address of the client submitting the message:

Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]);
by debug.poolp.org (OpenSMTPD) with ESMTP id 2028cae9;
for gil...@poolp.org;

Will become:

Received: by debug.poolp.org (OpenSMTPD) with ESMTP id f8e66416;
for gil...@poolp.org;"