SPF is failing because RoundCube's first hop is from localhost 127.0.0.1 - need it to be my server's IP
I have an email server that can send emails fine through email clients; however, when I successfully send from webmail (RoundCube), the first hop is coming from my webmail.mydomain.com using localhost 127.0.0.1 causing it to fail SPF validation.
I've tried setting etc/hosts to have 127.0.0.1 my.servername.com.
I also saw something about setting myhostname to a real hostname in /etc/postfix/main.cf, but I don't have that setting there and I'm not sure I should add it.
It seems like webmail is setup as having domain 127.0.0.1, but I'm not sure where I can check to make sure it's setup correctly.
Everything else has worked fine for years; I didn't realize this was failing until clients started using webmail more recently.
Environment: Ubuntu Server, Webmin, Virtualmin , Postfix, Dovecot, Apache, Roundcube

Edit: to clarify.. the message is sending fine without sending errors. The header of the message shows the first hop as coming from localhost, making it fail the spf check so it goes to junk, hits spam filters or is rejected on the recipients end.  I need to make it so the first hop comes from my proper IP address which is in my spf, not the 127.0.0.1 address that is failing.
I found lines inside of RoundCube's config.inc.php file that specified "localhost".  I've changed those to be the correct mailserver, but it has not fixed the issue.


I am guessing that it is postfix which is rejecting the message. It would be helpful if you told us how Roundcuve connect to the SMTP server, and what the logs from the SMTP server show for a failed, and for a successful message.

Added to the post.. I don't have send errors. It is just showing wrong info in the header upon receipt so it fails verification checks.

Please don't redact logs. Please tell us your domain name. Read this for more information. Redacting information only makes helping you harder.

@vidarlo - fair... I'll keep that in mind for future.  In this case, I felt like the relevant information is showing.  It's coming from a domain using the localhost loop and that is what is being put in the headers.  The other domains don't matter as much, I'm just trying to get rid of the 127.0.0.1 which is showing in the image.  Thanks for all the help - I've stripped the info in a postfix milter which is working.  Posted answer below.

This is the first time I hear of SPF looking at the 'Received' header. It seems like it would utterly defeat the point, with how easy it is for anyone to add fake headers. Is it your server that does this SPF check or is it the recipient's?

@Adam The reason for my question is that the Received headers are typically not used as a source for SPF checks - as they are trivially faked.

Thank you both! Perhaps they weren't the main cause? One client (of many) was sending email through our own postfix+webmail server that were going to spam.  All seemed to work fine when they used Outlook, but webmail went to spam.  Online tools to analyze headers / test deliverability showed the spf alignment failing - nothing else.  After removing this line, it no longer fails the tests - but not 100% this has fixed the problem - it was first step for me since I could see it fail.  Next = follow up with client to see if underlying issue is solved.

After searching for hours for a solution to change this header information, I've taken a different approach.  I've setup my postfix server to strip (regex replace) this line of the header information on it's way out.  Now, the emails do not include this IP address and they pass all checks.  This fixed the problem for me.
Here's where the answer came from: https://serverfault.com/a/1088766/470929
